# Usage of ASP.NET MVC for dual presentation and rest services.

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing the ASP.NET MVC5 web-application. Let's say that I already implemented admin panel with CMS in presentation layer : admin has full access to all CRUD operations.

Also I need to create Restful API that will only operate with HttpGet requests. Should I create another WebAPI based project in solution or simply can do following:

**RestfulController : Controller**

```
public ActionResult MyAwesomeMethod(int id){
 return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Or even if i need to support HttpPost request too, then, can I do the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public void MyBeautifulMethod(string name, string department){
 //TODO staff with the data...
}
```

Is it allowed approach or do I need to use only WebAPI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we are creating mvc controller you are inherting your controller from Controller class. When we are creating web-api controller then we inherit it from ApiController. So we cannot put api method and action method in same controller.

But a mvc project can have both type of controllers. It depends on you wheter to create web api controllers in same project or in different project.

Please mark as answer If I helped.

Comment: yeah, i understand the difference between Controller and ApiController. My question is about can we implement HttpGet and HttpPost methods of Restful by Controller : ActionResult : Json?

Comment: Dear webapi is another thing than returning json from action method. Yes you can return json from Action. You need to use return Json(yourObject);